# Vuetify: How to get current theme color?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Nuxt and Vuetify. If I write `<nuxt-link>`, Nuxt generates `<a>` tag and the link text is underlined and blue.

I can remove the underline as follows:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Next, I want to fix the color. However, the color depends on the theme (light mode or dark mode).

How to get current mode text color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it can be accessed with `this.$vuetify.theme`.

The docs are talking about setters but it can totally be used with getters too: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#light-and-dark

And you could change it with something like

```js
this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = '#4caf50'
```

Comment: Do I have to write conditional?  `if(this.$vuetify.theme.dark){color = this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark.primary}else{...}`

Comment: I guess. I don't know what/where/how you want to handle your code but this is a possibility yes. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
this.$vuetify.theme.currentTheme.primary
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and Vue 3, Nuxt 3, and Vuetify 3 are things... so what to do?

In my case I'm using Typescript and Script Setup so to access the current theme I do the following;

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

  const vTheme = useTheme()
  
  // use property
  const primaryColor = vTheme.current.value.colors.primary

  // use custom property with hyphens
  const myColor = vTheme.current.value.colors["my-color"]
</script>
```

For more details about the object returned from useTheme(), and how you can access/update themes/values, check out this section of the theme docs for Vuetify 3:

https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#theme-object-structure